# The heaptrack_print --suppressions option is always matching with all the memory leaks found, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: memory-leaks, heap-memory

I'm using **heaptrack** to find memory leaks.
The thing is that when I confirm a false positive, I create an entry in a `.supp` file to use it with **heaptrack_print** (--suppressions option). But a simple line always matches with absolutely everything, no matter the content of the line.

I'm on Manjaro, but the same happens in Ubuntu Jammy.

`$ heaptrack -v                                                                                                                                                                               heaptrack 1.4.0`

**test.cpp**

```
int main() {
  new int[10];
  return 0;
}
```

I compile the simple program

```
g++ -o test test.cpp
```

Generate the report

```
$ heaptrack ./test                                                                                                                                                                                      
heaptrack output will be written to "./heaptrack/heaptrack.test.185844.zst"
/usr/lib/heaptrack/libheaptrack_preload.so
starting application, this might take some time...
heaptrack stats:
    allocations:            2
    leaked allocations:     1
    temporary allocations:  0
Heaptrack finished! Now run the following to investigate the data:

  heaptrack --analyze ./heaptrack/heaptrack.test.185844.zst"

heaptrack_gui detected, automatically opening the file...
```

Analyzing with **heaptrack_print** we see the memory leak

```
$  heaptrack_print --print-leaks true --print-allocators false --print-peaks false --peak-limit 10 --sub-peak-limit 5 --print-temporary false --print-suppressions true --file heaptrack.test.185844.zst
reading file "heaptrack.test.185844.zst" - please wait, this might take some time...
Debuggee command was: ./test
finished reading file, now analyzing data:

MEMORY LEAKS
40B leaked over 1 calls from
main
  in ./heaptrack/test
40B leaked over 1 calls from:


total runtime: 0.00s.
calls to allocation functions: 2 (2000/s)
temporary memory allocations: 0 (0/s)
peak heap memory consumption: 72.74K
peak RSS (including heaptrack overhead): 3.08M
total memory leaked: 40B
```

Now, when I use the `.supp` file

`leak:any_func`

This is the result, I expect the same output as before, but the memory leak is ignored

```
$ heaptrack_print --print-leaks true --print-allocators false --print-peaks false --peak-limit 10 --sub-peak-limit 5 --print-temporary false --print-suppressions true --suppression ignore.supp --file heaptrack.test.185844.zst
reading file "heaptrack.test.185844.zst" - please wait, this might take some time...
Debuggee command was: ./test
finished reading file, now analyzing data:

MEMORY LEAKS

total runtime: 0.001000s.
calls to allocation functions: 2 (2000/s)
temporary memory allocations: 0 (0/s)
peak heap memory consumption: 72.74K
peak RSS (including heaptrack overhead): 3.08M
total memory leaked: 0B
suppressed leaks: 40B
Suppressions used:
         matches           leaked pattern
               2              40B
```

Thank you.